# Selecting max value between columns and replacing non min values to 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, min

I have 4 columns in table that each have different category values. I would like to find the maximum value between the columns and keep only that while turning all other values to 0. How can I go about doing this.

Reproducible example

```
CREATE TABLE #df (
    cat1 int,
    cat2 int,
    cat3 int,
    cat4 int
);


INSERT INTO #df
(
    cat1,
    cat2,
    cat3,
    cat4
)
VALUES
(   1, 0, 3, 4 ),
(   0, 2, 0, 4 ),
(   1, 2, 0, 0 ),
(   0, 0, 0, 4 )

SELECT * FROM #df
```

Final Table:

| Cat1 | Cat2 | Cat3 | Cat4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 4 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 4 |
| 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 4 |

My attempt: This is close to what I want but instead of keeping the old columns, it creates a new column with the max value. I would like the same 4 columns as before but the non max values replaced to 0.

```
SELECT Cat1, Cat2, Cat3, Cat4, 
    (SELECT Max(Col) FROM (VALUES (Cat1), (Cat2), (Cat3), (Cat4)) AS X(Col)) AS TheMax
FROM #df
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: I don't understand your desired result, it looks like you have the *min* value from each column

Comment: @Stu i have fixed that. My apologies.

Comment: what should happen if the max value is repeated in two cats?

Comment: @Horaciux The way the data is set up, that cannot happen. Cat1 can only be 1 or 0, cat 2 only 2 or 0 and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use your existing statement as part of an *apply* then you can use an inline if (or case expression) to pick the required value:

```
select
  Iif(cat1 = themax, cat1, 0) cat1,
  Iif(cat2 = themax, cat2, 0) cat2,
  Iif(cat3 = themax, cat3, 0) cat3,
  Iif(cat4 = themax, cat4, 0) cat4
from t
cross apply (
  select Max(Col) from (values(Cat1), (Cat2), (Cat3), (Cat4))x(Col)
)m(themax)
```